# Where should I put an Add button in a Bootstrap Modal dialog?

Tags: usability, forms, buttons, modal-windows, bootstrap

I have a UI like this designed at the moment with Bootstrap modal:

[image]

I was thinking the "Add Shift" button looks misplaced. Would there be any better placement for the button so it doesn't look so out of place, yet still easily accessible?

I was thinking of adding (Add) to the tabs, but wouldn't that also affect usability?

Comment: I think it looks misplaced because there is no room to breath. There is a lot of space that can be created to allow the information to breath. Try spacing things out.

Comment: Also, is shift 1 (and 2) clickable? I highly suggest you don't make it a button if it is. It seems like a secondary action.

Comment: They are clickable; they pop up a dropdown if clicked, with actions like Delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to make UI much simpler and obvious, saved a lot of space in the process! :)

[image]

Comment: A couple of points. 1) It's not clear how to add a shift, and 2) as a general rule, the tabs should mimic their real world equivalents and connect to the main body they represent. The horizontal line above the Monday row breaks this.

Comment: @dennisless Make sense; how's this? https://www.dropbox.com/s/t0735k7xiaasiju/Screenshot%202014-12-11%2020.50.08.png?dl=0

Comment: Tab looks good (though I think the tabs are a particular weakness in Bootstrap. They're arguably _too_ stripped down and flat. I'd be tempted to add some contrast color to the inactive tabs (active tab > white like the page, inactive tabs > light gray) just to strengthen the pattern. Also, as final note, your layout would really benefit from touch more whitespace. Just a few more pixels of vertical space between the horizontal rows. That would make it look less cramped and make parsing the page a bit easier.

Comment: @dennisless thanks for the comment! i'll be adding a bit more margin to the items in the rows. although i agree with your comment about the tabs, I find mobile is tending more toward flat design so i'll just leave it like that for now.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, right side above of the table would be a better place, it looks good if it  display in same size of the button and font size which is used for - Shift 1 button
[image]